# How can i use Python to execute adb commands?

Tags: android, python

I want to create a python script which could be used to execute Android adb commands. 
I had a look at https://github.com/rbrady/python-adb but can't seem to make it work perfectly. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This tool should do the work.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyadb/0.1.1

I had to modify a few functions to have it operate on Python 2.7 and use subprocess instead. Here the modified code in my version:

```
def __build_command__(self,cmd):
    if self.__devices is not None and len(self.__devices) > 1 and self.__target is None:
        self.__error = "Must set target device first"
        return None

    if type(cmd) is tuple:
        a = list(cmd)
    elif type(cmd) is list:
        a = cmd
    else:
        a = [cmd]
    a.insert(0, self.__adb_path)
    if self.__target is not None:
        a.insert(1, ['-s', self.__target])

    return a

def run_cmd(self, cmd):
    """
    Run a command against adb tool ($ adb <cmd>)
    """
    self.__clean__()

    if self.__adb_path is None:
        self.__error = "ADB path not set"
        return

    try:
        args = self.__build_command__(cmd)
        if args is None:
            return
        # print 'args>', args
        cmdp = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.__output, self.__error = cmdp.communicate()
        retcode = cmdp.wait()
        # print 'stdout>', self.__output
        # print 'stderr>', self.__error
        if retcode < 0:
            print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
        else:
            return
    except OSError, e:
        self.__error = str(e)

    return
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `monkeyrunner` tool for that. From it's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html):

> Besides using the monkeyrunner API itself, you can use the standard Python os and subprocess modules to call Android tools such as Android Debug Bridge.

Answer (score -1):

The [python-adb](https://github.com/google/python-adb) project implements the USB communications layer and up, even providing an Android adb-like API for easy conversion.